# css3 last-child not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have match listings dynamically generated. After each member I display a li that displays VS within it. However the very last ul li in the div match shouldnt be visible. Any ideas how I can do that?
HTML

```
<style>
    .match {
    }
    .match ul {
    }
    .match ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 50px;
    } 
    .match ul li:last-child {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="match">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/wade-barrett/member">Wade Barrett</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/shaemus/member">Shaemus</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/randy-orton/member">Randy Orton</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/john-cena/member">John Cena</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/edge/member">Edge</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/chris-jericho/member">Chris Jericho</a></li>
        <li style="">VS</li>
      </ul>

      <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you just edited your question into strange words of no meaning?

Comment: @David: I can make out the word IGNORE.

Comment: i think he found the answer to it and didnt know how to acknowledge that.

Comment: @Boltclock's a Unicorn, I saw the words in those words, but the words themselves weren't 'ignore,' or English language. I just wondered why he'd revoked your edit to go with whatever that was meant to be.

Comment: @Davis: I think @sushil gave a plausible reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `:last-child` pseudo-class should apply to the `ul`, not `li`, because you want VS text of the last `ul` of the list to be hidden. By applying the pseudo-class to `li`, you're applying styles to *the last `li` of **every** `ul`*, which is incorrect.

You should also apply a `class` attribute to the `li` elements with the VS text so that it's more convenient to match with a class selector.

Change

```
<li style="">VS</li>
```

to

```
<li class="vs">VS</li>
```

And use this instead of your current `:last-child` selector:

```
.match ul:last-child li.vs {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What browser are you using, IE does not support it. The latest version of the other browsers do, but I would recommend placing a class on it to make it 100%.

Comment: No, the spec says `:last-child` was only introduced in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo). There is no mention of `:last-child` in the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). +1 for browser support issues though.

Comment: Sorry, you know I did not realize that `last-child` was not in CSS2 when `first-child` is. Thanks for pointing that out, I have removed that from my answer.

Comment: that's alright. It *is* rather strange they didn't think to introduce `last-child` till CSS3...